# Module, End(M), acts

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

> What it means for a module $M$ and the endomorphism ring $\text{End}(M)$ that $\text{End}(M)$ acts diagonally on $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer?

Also, if $G=(r_{ij})$ is a matrix with entries in the ring $R$ why $$\text{ann}_{M^n} G=\{c^- \in M^n | \sum c_i r_{ij}=0 \text{ for each }j\}$$ is an $\text{End}(M)$-submodule of $M^n$, where $\text{End}(M)$ acts diagonally as above.

Answer (score 1):

Acts diagonally means acting on each summand i.e. $A (m_1, ..., m_n)=(Am_1, ..., Am_n)$. The second fact is trivial.